# Двумерный массив,нужно добавить свои значения

Tags: javascript

Написать функцию заполнения пользовательскими данными двумерного массива. Длину основного массива и внутренних массивов задаёт пользователь. Значения всех элементов всех массивов задаёт пользователь.

```js
function arrAdd() {
    let arr = [];
    let amount = +prompt("Введите количество массивов в первом массиве");

    for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        arr.push([]);

        let amount2 = prompt("Введите количество елементов" + (i + 1));

        for(let j = 0; j < amount2; j++) {
            let text = prompt("Введите текст" + (j + 1));
            arr.push([i][text]);
        }
    }

    console.log(arr);
}

let functionResult = arrAdd();
```

Результат должен быть приблизительно похож элементы могут быть разные значения: arr= [[elem1,elem2,elem3],[elem,elem],[elem]]. Скорее всего мой код вообще не правильный